# How to pass multidimensional array in arbitrary size as function argument in GO

Tags: arrays, go

I'm new to GO. There is the problem I'm facing.

The function takes a 2D array in arbitrary size as argument:

```
func PrintArray(a [][]string) {
    for _, v1 := range a {
        for _, v2 := range v1 {
            fmt.Printf("%s ", v2)
        }
        fmt.Printf("\n")
    }
}
```

As you can see, since the nested loop uses `range`. The size of the array really doesn't matter.

But when I try to call this function:

```
a := [3][2]string{
    {"line", "tiger"},
    {"cat", "dog"},
    {"pigeon", "hamster"},
}
PrintArray(a[:])
```

It complains about:

> cannot use a[:] (type [][2]string) as type [][]string in argument to PrintArray

However, it won't compile with `a[:][:]` either.

What is the correct way to define a multidimensional array in arbitrary size in GO lang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, [array types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) and [slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) are distinct. Pass slices to slices.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := [][]string{
        {"line", "tiger"},
        {"cat", "dog"},
        {"pigeon", "hamster"},
    }
    PrintSlices(a)
}

func PrintSlices(a [][]string) {
    for _, v1 := range a {
        for _, v2 := range v1 {
            fmt.Printf("%s ", v2)
        }
        fmt.Printf("\n")
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/3mPDTIEUQmT

Output:

```
line tiger 
cat dog 
pigeon hamster
```

---

To allocate a matrix:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func NewMatrix(rows, cols int) [][]int {
    m := make([][]int, rows)
    for r := range m {
        m[r] = make([]int, cols)
    }
    return m
}

func main() {
    m := NewMatrix(3, 2)
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qvwQu2giRcP

Output:

```
[[0 0] [0 0] [0 0]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to define the size of inner array?

Comment: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. This should work

```
a := [][]string{
    {"line", "tiger"},
    {"cat", "dog"},
    {"pigeon", "hamster"},
}
PrintArray(a[:])
```

From the error messages, I would guess that arrays defined with size are of different types.

For example, if the `PrintArray` looks like this:

`func PrintArray(a [3][2]string) {`

Then you can pass it an array defined as:

`a := [3][2]string`.

If we vary the numbers in either the `PrintArray` method or `a`, so that they differ, we get an error message that says:

`cannot use a (type [3][2]string) as type [3][1]string in argument to PrintArray`